# Make favorite button shows marked without reloading page Ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, ionic-framework, favorite

I write an Ionic page that shows a list of posts, each post has a favorite button (star icon) for users to mark it. When I click on a favorite button, data will be inserted into the database, but the icon is not immediately marked. After reloading page, it's marked. So how to make the icon marked right away when clicking on it.

Here is my page code, it uses `$scope.post_infos` to show data, if variable "marked" exists, favorite button will show star icon, otherwise outline star icon:

```
<ion-list>  //ng-controller is recuitmentCtrl
<div ng-repeat="post_info in post_infos" >
     <ion-item>
     <div class=" item-button-right">
          <a ng-click="showContent(post_info.id)">
             <div class="post">
                  <div class= "title">{{post_info.title}}</div>
                  <div class= "description">{{post_info.description}}</div>
             </div> 
          </a>
          <button class="button button-icon i" ng-click="isFavorite(post_info.id)">
             <i ng-class="{'icon ion-android-star-outline': !post_info.marked, 
                        'icon ion-android-star': post_info.marked}"></i>
          </button>
     </div>
     </ion-item>
</div>
</ion-list>
```

In my controller.js

```
.controller('recuitmentCtrl', ['$scope', '$state', function ($scope, $state,) {

    var ref = firebase.database().ref('posts');
    var titles, descriptions;
    $scope.post_infos = [];

    ref.on('value' ,function(snapshot){
        var userID = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
        $scope.post_infos = [];

        snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot){

            var marked = firebase.database().ref('users/'+ userID + '/favorites/' + childSnapshot.key);
            marked.on('value', function(snapshot_user){
            var obj = { 
                "id":           childSnapshot.key,
                "title":        childSnapshot.val().title,
                "description":  childSnapshot.val().description,
                "marked":       snapshot_user.child("marked").val()
            };
            $scope.post_infos.push(obj);
        })
    });
});

    $scope.showContent = function(param){
        $state.go('postdetail',{postID: param});
    };

    $scope.isFavorite = function(postID){
       var userID = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
       var userRef = firebase.database().ref('users/'+ userID + '/favorites/' + postID);
       userRef.set({
          marked: true
       }).then(function(result){
    });
}
```

}])

Here is my database:

[image: Firebase database]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the variable `post_info` when it's marked as favorite, here are two ways to do it:

Controller

```
$scope.isFavorite = function(post){
   var userID = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
   var userRef = firebase.database().ref('users/'+ userID + '/favorites/' + post.id);
   //post.marked = true; //instant feedback
   userRef.set({
      marked: true
   }).then(function(result){
       //post.marked = true; //will mark as favorite as soon as the server accepts the request
   });
```

Template

```
<button class="button button-icon i" ng-click="isFavorite(post_info)">
         <i ng-class="{'icon ion-android-star-outline': !post_info.marked, 
                    'icon ion-android-star': post_info.marked}"></i>
</button>
```

Comment: It worked like a charm. I tried both of the comment lines and both of it worked, but it also adds the post I clicked on at the bottom of the list. So, I change marked.on("value") to maked.once("value"). Perfect!!. Thank you so much!!

Comment: Hi mcrvaz, I did what you said and it worked, but now I face a new problem about ref.on('value') when I post a new article. I think you can understand what it is without seeing my postController code, my postController is to post a new article, when clicking submit, it redirects to the page above. The problem here is each post of the list show twice, but if I comment all the lines of *variable marked*, it works. Maybe it's related to callback, I've tried some ref.off, but it doesn't help. Could you help me, please!

Comment: It seems you are watching for changes with `ref.on('value')` and pushing a new `post_info` to the list everytime the value is changed with
`$scope.post_infos.push(obj);`.
Maybe you can check if the `post_info` already exists on the list before adding or simply update the value on the list instead of adding a new one.